# How do I iterate through the values of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to use the value of mountainRange[0] to calculate the value of mountainRange[1], and then the value of [1] to calculate [2], and so on.

```
 public static double[] generateMountains(int size, double steepness, double maxHeight)
  {
    double [] mountainRange = new double[size];    
mountainRange[0] = maxHeight/2;    

    for (int i = 1; i < mountainRange.length; i++)
     {
       mountainRange[i] = getNextPoint(mountainRange [i], steepness, maxHeight);
       System.out.println("point is: " + mountainRange[i]);
     }
```

So the problem is the mountainRange [i] is always equal to the first value given in the main method (10). I tried:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < mountainRange.length; i++)
 {
   mountainRange[i] = getNextPoint(mountainRange [i-1], steepness, maxHeight);
```

But I get the same result, the only difference is that the value will now randomly change. From 10.0 to 9.97... or 6.78..., or sometimes it will remain 10 all the way through.

also, the getNextPoint method does

```
    public static double getNextPoint (double height, double steepness, double maxHeight)
  {
    steepness = steepness - (Math.random() * steepness);

    height = height + steepness;
    return height;
```

I printed steepness and it doesn't change from what was set in the main method. What it's supposed to do is: if for example steepness 3.0 is given, the actual steepness will be a random number between -3.0 and 3.0.

Also, I tried moving what is in the getNextPoint method inside generateMountains, before the for loop. Still, steepness doesn't change.

Comment: `Math.random()` will return a double between 0 and 1. So, if steepness is 3, the actual steepness will be a random number between 0 and 3.

Comment: The third line of your bottom code really means `steepness = steepness * (1 - Math.random());`. This doesn't seem like what you want.